# rel=nofollow, JavaScript slider content, SEO

Tags: javascript, links, nofollow

My website has all content on one page. I'm using JavaScript to slide (animate) between the various "subpages", so only the subpage content is shown.

The menu buttons are as this: `<a href="#welcome">Welcome</a>` with a `return false`.

In regards to Google, other bots and SEO, would it be best to use `rel="nofollow"` on those menu links?

I mean, the menu links don't point to anything, only when viewing with a browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Nofollow` isn't going to change how search engines process those links.

- Search engine bots don't request hash links (or `javascript:`) links from your server.  The presence or absense of `nofollow` won't change this.
- From a PageRank point of view, those links are not passing any PageRank to anything else.  There is no need to use `nofollow` to prevent PageRank from being passed.  In the worst case, adding a `nofollow` could cause some of your PageRank to be discarded when it wasn't before.
- Those links were created by you.  There is no need to apply a `nofollow` to indicate the links were placed by users.

I don't see any way that `nofollow` would help.  It would likely just be ignored, but in the worst case it could hurt.

Answer (score 2):

[Google says](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en) the `rel="nofollow"` attribute on links must be used only for links the webmaster doesn't control insertion on pages (therefore, in general useful for comments from users who put links to their sites...).

In your case, you insert these links by yourself to help users navigation. That's why, you must avoid the `rel="nofollow"` attribute on links.

Moreover, unlike you say, these links point to sub-sections of your pages, by JavaScript but they point to something.

Answer (score 2):

Only outgoing (internal or external) links are being involved in the PageRank calculation.

Actually in page named anchors may help your SEO by constructing named links in SERP. Have a look [here](http://seogadget.com/implementing-named-anchors-to-improve-your-serps/).

For the `rel="nofollow"` attribute:

> `Rel="nofollow"` should **not** be used for PageRank sculpting. When you
>   add `nofollow` to a link, like in your example, you actually
>   say to search engines that this link cannot be trusted.

`Rel="nofollow"` does not exclude a link from the PageRank calculation, but it only says to bots, not to follow this link and don't pass anchortext.

For example, on a page you have 10 (internal external there is no difference) links, and let says there is 50 PageRank juice for this page.

To calculate how much juice each link gets, we have to divide the total juice with the total amount of links, in this example 50 / 10 = 5 juice per link.

If all links are followed, all your links will get 5 juice.
If you nofollow 2 of them, the total juice that each link gets is not changed. So you will have 8 links with 5 juice and 2 links with 0 juice.

This is not happening:
50 / (total links - nofollowed) = 50 / 8 = 6.25 juice per link.

To sum up, when you nofollow a link it doesnt remove it from the PageRank calculation.

You can find more information [here](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/pagerank-sculpting/).